How to replace old roles with new ones when updating user data in the database?
The User object has a OneToMany relationship with the Role object.
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {}

    public User(Long id, String username, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(Long id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}

The Role object has a ManyToOne relationship with the User object.
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User userId;

    @Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    public Role() {}

    public Role(Long id, User userId, String roleName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
}

Now when I try to UPDATE existing user data by
userRepository.save(new User(existingId, newUsername, newPassword, newRoles));

username and password are updated successfully, but with user roles things are different. The existing roles of this user are not replaced with new ones, but rather added to the existing ones.
In simple terms, I want that when a user's data is UPDATING, the new roles will be removed and replaced with new ones.
Is it possible to achieve this effect, for example, by changing the CascadeType or other simple elegant methods?
